# How to remove orphan records?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I am using CascadeType.ALL but when I try to delete a record it just delete the record not its associated records.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
public List<CartItem> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

My tables are

```
cart
cartitem
cart_cartitem
```

When I use the following it just remove the record of cart_cartitem not the record of cartitem.

```
cart.getItems().remove(0);
session.update(cart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented [equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406170/664577) correctely? Also I believe that you are trying to remove orphans.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", 
   cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<CartItem> getItems();
```

Comment: can you please have a look at my other question as well thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148991/how-to-add-data-of-different-records-to-a-single-record